# how to use System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect to decrypt ciphertext between different server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, katana

My asp.net site has two server for load balance. I found that if the authentication cookie(.AspNet.Application) were encrypted by the server 1, then it can't be decrypt by server 2. I have already set the machiekey of the two servers to the same value. In addition, I found that System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect method can't decrypt ciphertext which was encrypt by another server that has the same machinekey. However, it works well in the same server. The site used web form technology before, but now it used web form+mvc in one solution.
my encrypt code fragment as below:

```
var bytes = System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcd1234"),
        "M", "A", "v1");
        this.textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

decrypt code fragment as below:

`var bytes = System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(this.textBox2.Text),
            "M", "A", "v1");
            this.textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);`

Could anyone help me please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you put machinekey in web.config, like

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <machineKey
      validationKey="your validationKey"
      decryptionKey="your decryptionKey"
      validation="SHA1"
      decryption="AES"
    />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thank you Rainmaker. Yeah! It works well now, but why it doesn't work if I place the machinekey in machine.config file?  The file path is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config. And my project's target framework is ".net framework 4.5.2"

Comment: please check IIS's Machine Key is your setting value. Make sure that the <machineKey> section has identical, explicit keys (that is, do not use the AutoGenerate option for attributes in the <machineKey> section) across the Web farm in the following scenarios: 
When you use Forms authentication.
When you run session state in StateServer mode.
When you want ViewState to be available across a Web farm because the enableViewStateMAC attribute is set to True by default.

Comment: Thank you Rainmaker. I have another question. I used console application and web application to protected and unprotected each other. I found that I must set the machinekey in app.config of console application, or the console application can't unprotect the ciphertext protected by web application. Is there any special reason in console application?

Comment: because your console app is use C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config. iis x64 will use  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config. you can change console app's platform from "Any CPU" to "x64" and console app will work well. ^_^

Comment: RainMaker, you are so wonderful.  Your machinekey of Framework( not 64) remind me that my application pool in IIs has enable 32 bit application and I didn't set the machinekey of Framework(not 64). Now I have fixed problem perfectly. Thank you!